# Having a function return a boolean and an address? C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

I am trying to have a function return a boolean and an address in memory.

I am loading a file from an archive and would like it to return A. if the file was found and B. a pointer to the file in memory after it is loaded. I realize that I cannot have two return types so I have the function as a boolean so it can tell me more importantly if the file exists in the archive. I figured I would do something like this:

```
// Hold the location of the file
char* location = NULL;

if(!archive.getFile(name, location))
{
    errorLog.writeError("Could not find the file!");
    return false;
}
```

If the file is not found, the function that calls the getFile will return false indicating the file was not found. That works great. But I am trying to figure out how to directly modify the pointer 'location' from within the getFile function.

Do I pass in the pointer? Or do I pass in the address of the pointer and modify it?

Here is the function in my header:

```
bool archive::getFile(string filename, char& location)
```

So to recap, I want to pass in the 'location' pointer, have it point to the file in the archive from getFile function and then when it returns, be able to use the 'location' pointer to access the file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return a pointer, and a null pointer if the thing is not found.

```
char *getFile(std::string name) {
  return nullptr; // or just 0
}
```

Then you can do:

```
if ((location = archive.getFile(name)) != 0) {
   // found
}
```

But that looks like C code.
Alternatively:

- return an empty `std::string` in the error case
- return a bool, but pass a non-const reference to a string

Or indeed pass a pointer-to-pointer or a reference-to-pointer, but that's the least "idiomatic" C++ you could do IMO.

Comment: You could also throw an exception if the file is not found. This allows you to have a much finer control over the error messages, as you can "return" quite a lot of different errors.

Comment: @Thilo: that's a matter of opinion, but I wouldn't consider an exception here - I'm assuming not finding a file in an archive is something that is supposed to happen under normal circumstances, so should be handled by normal control flow. Keep exceptions for exceptional conditions. (But as stated, this is subjective/depends on context/coding standards/surrounding code/etc.)

Comment: @Mat: Argument granted. I suppose that is in fact a matter of context and taste.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a structure or even a class containing a boolean and the pointer that you want to return:

```
struct MyType
{
  bool exist;
  char* whatever;
};
```

and then your function returns a MyType struct.

Comment: I really like this idea. For now, because I am using structs, I am going to go with the other char* suggestions but thank you. I will remember that I can do this in the future. +1

Answer (score 1):

First of all the declaration of your function is not correct it should not get a reference to char(char&) but a pointer to char. It should be:

```
bool archive::getFile(string filename, char* location)
```

If you want to modify the pointer you should pass a pointer to it(i.e. double pointer) or a reference to pointer(which is not a good solution in my opinion - mixing references and pointers may become confusing). So in fact here is how the declaration should look like

```
bool archive::getFile(string filename, char** location)
```

In the standart library whenever there is a need of a function that returns a pointer and should indicate wether the pointer was successfully created, NULL is returned to indicated failure. So consider making your function declaration:

```
char* archive::getFile(string filename)
```

And make it return the location if the file is present in the archive and NULL if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the two values in a std::pair. I generally prefer each variable to be used for only one use but there is a tradition of overloading the pointer with NULL to mean something else. If you need to return more than two values you can use boost::tuple.